# How to export to csv every write-host?

Tags: powershell

I have the following script that displays the connections of each database in the server

I want to create and export to csv the "server", "database", and "connection info" column headers, and basically output the server name,DBName,and connection information to corresponding column.

I looked into `PSCustomObject` but i am not sure how to implement this exactly in my script

```
write-host "`r`n            Server            |               DataBase               |       Connection info      `r`n" -foregroundcolor white -backgroundcolor darkyellow

Import-Module SqlServer

$oldAS = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$oldAS.connect("server1")

foreach ($db in $oldAS.Databases){
    $compatibility_level = $db.CompatibilityLevel
    if($compatibility_level -lt 1200)
    {
      $OLDdbName = $db.Name
      Write-Host $OLDdbName -Fore green
[PSCustomObject]@{
    DataBase = $OLDdbName
}
      $db.DataSources | ForEach-Object{write-host "$($_.ConnectionString)";
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Connection Info" = $_.ConnectionString
              }
}
    }
    else
    {
        $AS = new-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server
        $AS.Connect("server1")

        foreach ($dbt in $AS.Databases | Where-Object{$compatibility_level -ge 1200} ){
          $dbName = $dbt.Name
          Write-Host $dbName
   [PSCustomObject]@{
        DataBase = $dbName
    }
          if(($dbt.model.datasources[0]).GetType().Name -match "ProviderDataSource") 
          {
            write-host "$($dbt.model.datasources[0].ConnectionString)"
            }
          else {
                #$dbt.model.datasources[0].ConnectionDetails.ToString(); #ToJson
                write-host "$($dbt.model.datasources[0].Credential.ToString())"
   [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Connection Info" = "$($dbt.model.datasources[0].Credential.ToString())"
    }
            }
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path .\CONNECTIONS_LOG.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

EDIT:

```
Import-Module SqlServer

$oldAS = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$oldAS.connect("server1")

#create .net array object
$exportObject = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

#create ordered dictionary so column names
#come out in the ordered they were created
$rowObject = [ordered]@{}

foreach ($db in $oldAS.Databases){
    $compatibility_level = $db.CompatibilityLevel
    if($compatibility_level -lt 1200)
    {
      $OLDdbName = $db.Name
      Write-Host $OLDdbName -Fore green
      $db.DataSources | ForEach-Object{
      write-host "$($_.ConnectionString)"

      $rowObject.'Connection' = $($_.ConnectionString)
      $exportObject.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $rowObject)) | Out-Null
      }

      $rowObject.'Database' = $OLDdbName 
      $exportObject.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $rowObject)) | Out-Null
    }
    else
    {
        $AS = new-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server
        $AS.Connect("server1")

        foreach ($dbt in $AS.Databases | Where-Object{$compatibility_level -ge 1200} ){
          $dbName = $dbt.Name
          Write-Host $dbName

          $rowObject.'Database' = $dbName
            $exportObject.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $rowObject)) | Out-Null

          if(($dbt.model.datasources[0]).GetType().Name -match "ProviderDataSource") 
          {
            write-host "$($dbt.model.datasources[0].ConnectionString)"
                $rowObject.'Connection' = $($dbt.model.datasources[0].ConnectionString)
                $exportObject.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $rowObject)) | Out-Null
            }
          else {
                #$dbt.model.datasources[0].ConnectionDetails.ToString(); #ToJson
                write-host "$($dbt.model.datasources[0].Credential.ToString())"

                $rowObject.'Connection' = $($dbt.model.datasources[0].Credential.ToString()) 
                $exportObject.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $rowObject)) | Out-Null
            }
        }
    }
}

$exportObject | Export-CSV "C:\temp\dbinfo.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ','
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to decipher what your script is doing, but here is a Powershell script that uses sqlps to obtain database information from the default SQL instance on my local machine. It loads the info for each database into a PowerShell object and adds the object to a .NET array. The .NET array is then exported to a csv file.

My SQL Server name is toshiba-bill

```
cls
Import-Module "sqlps" -DisableNameChecking

#create .net array object
$exportObject = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

#create ordered dictionary so column names
#come out in the ordered they were created
$rowObject = [ordered]@{}

#the sqlps dir SQLSERVER command returns 
#Name, Status, Containment Type, Recovery Model, CompatLvl, Collation, and Owner
#for each database in the default instance
$databases = @(dir SQLSERVER:\\SQL\toshiba-bill\Default\Databases) 

foreach ($database in $databases)
{
    $rowObject.'Database name' = $database.Name
    $rowObject.Status = $database.Status
    $rowObject.'Recovery Model' = $database.RecoveryModel
    $exportObject.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $rowObject)) | Out-Null
}

$exportObject | Export-CSV "C:\temp\dbinfo.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ','
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Can you use rowobject of the same columns in another forloop and wouldnt the headers be outputted again? for example, if you had another forloop, and you had $rowObject.'Database name' = $hadoopDB.Name, would you have to again use $exportObject.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $rowObject)) | Out-Null and then append to the csv? but in that case, wouldnt the Database name header column be replicated twice? or you only have to "Add" to exportobject only when you have new columns?

Comment: @Cataster: You can add more $rowObjects to the list of 'Recovery Model' if you'd like, but in order to keep the list usable, the rows you'd add would typically use the same column names, i.e., 'Database name', Status, and 'Recovery Model'. If you have other data you want to capture, the you'd use other column names for that data. I think you need to read up on the basics of PowerShell objects. Maybe this will help: [https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/powershell-basics-custom-objects](https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/powershell-basics-custom-objects)

Comment: @Cataster: p.s - its not that you output every write-host to a csv. Rather, in order to output to a csv, you need to prepare a collection of PowerShell objects that you then output to csv typically using the `Export-CSV` cmdlet

Comment: so i just tried this and its wroking great, but there is an issue: $exportObject.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $rowObject)) | Out-Null is getting overwritten somehow at every time i add a new object throughout script

Comment: @Cataster: Please add your current and complete script to the bottom of your original question - I'll take a look

Comment: Ok, i think i know whats happening...$exportObject.Add is supposed to be only once declared. not at every rowobject , and instead at the end of the for loop